# Error function fit of data

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

I have this experimental data set which I know should follow the Complementary error function.

My goal is to find the **σ of the associated gaussian distribution**.

However, I cannot seem to do it in any way using `NonlinearModelFit`. Could you please give me some hints?

The data is in a list of lists, e.g.:

```
data = ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BtcXHh9c"];
```

And when plotted it looks like this:

[image: ListPlot[Transpose@data]]

Comment: where is the data?

Comment: Actually, I should have first of all put the data in ordered pairs: {{x1,y1},{x2,y2} ... }.

Comment: I think you mean something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJiSF.png).

Comment: To fix data download: `data = ReplaceRepeated[
  ToExpression[
    ToString@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BtcXHh9c"]][[1, 
    1]], {a___, {b_, Null}, {c_}, d___} :> {a, {b, c}, 
    d}]; ListPlot[data]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything unusual here that can't be found in the documentation. Normalization parameters in the x and y dimensions (b, and a, respectively) can be added into the model, as can the x-axis shift (parameter c).  Parameter estimates are taken from a look at the original data.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  a Erfc[b (x + c)], {{a, 8 10^-8}, {b, 1/10}, {c, -35000}}, x]
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 35000, 35400}, Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: agree with your comment. Originally the data posted was not such a beautiful fit...hence my hamfisted approach to force a function where NonlinearModelFit did not work...timing...but at least it led to provision of correct data...though this fit seems to good to be true

Comment: @ubpdqn +1 for "spending" the time on the bad data!

Comment: Thanks. I need to ask, are parameter estimates in NonlinearModelFit necessary?

Comment: @Danno I can't think of a time when knowing the uncertainty of your parameter model is **not** necessary.  Get them with `nlm["ParameterTable"]`

Comment: But, and it really may be a newbie question on many levels, isn't the fitting algorithm's job to find the parameter values? I am talking about the estimates you gave, e.g. the `8 10^-8`besides $a$ etc. Notice I may not have fully understood your last comment.

Comment: @Danno I misunderstood your question.  Using least squares to fit a nonlinear model requires a guess at the parameters.  If you don't provide a guess, Mathematica guesses for you.  In your case, with x and y dimensions varying by ~13 orders of magnitude, the default guess for the parameters (I think it would be `a=b=c=1`) will likely not provide a *best* fit.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little unsure what the aim is here. Looking at the data only the first third of the plot could be fitted to `Erfc` like function.

I post this, perhaps, as motivation.

```
d = Transpose@data;
ListPlot[ds = SortBy[d, #[[1]] &], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Extracting the part of plot I referred to:

```
fd = ds[[1 ;; 35]]
fdlp = ListPlot[fd]
```

[image]

Now as a rather ugly approach to trying to fit desired function. This will involve rescaling, removal of troublesome 0 or negative values, logarithmic transform and back transforming. This is NOT ideal and am sure expert users will have better approaches (assuming this is what is desired).

```
{min, max} = Through[{Min, Max}[fd[[All, 2]]]];
res = Rescale[fd[[All, 2]]];
trans = Transpose[{fd[[All, 1]], res}];
int = Interpolation[trans, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
{xmin, xmax} = {34800.`, 35137.`};
dif[u_] := D[int[x], x] /. x -> u
w = {#, -dif[#]} & @@@ trans;
wlp = ListPlot[w]
peak = Cases[w, {_, Max[w[[All, 2]]]}][[1, 1]]
shift = Cases[{#1 - peak, #2} & @@@ w, {_, _?Positive}];
lg = {#1, Log@#2} & @@@ shift;
lm = LinearModelFit[lg, {1, x^2}, x]
func[u_] := Exp[Normal@lm] /. x -> u
Show[Plot[func[t - peak], {t, xmin, xmax}], wlp]
ex = Rescale[v, {0, 1}, {min, max}]
h[u_] := ex /. v -> u;
soln[t_] := NIntegrate[func[x], {x, -Infinity, t}]
Show[fdlp, Plot[h[1 - soln[x - peak]], {x, xmin, xmax}]]
```

The derivative of interpolating function (and fit):

[image]

The final "fit":

[image]

The fit expression (with back transforming and rescaling):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however I didn't notice that the data I published was corrupted. I just edited the question with the actual data, that looks way different, and I am quite sure it fits a complementary error function (apart from some two constant pieces at the beginning and end of the data set).

Comment: @Danno...ok...bobthechemist has provided the very clear answer